# Drawing a diagram with long arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I have drawn this diagram. But I don't know how to make the arrow between d and e more long, so the diagram become more well-arranged.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
a \arrow{r} \arrow{d} &b \arrow{r} &c \arrow{ld}\\
d\arrow{r} & e \arrow{r} & f \arrow{r} &g\\
h\arrow{r} \arrow{u} & i\arrow{u}
\end{tikzcd} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Isn't my answer what you were looking for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
a \arrow{r} \arrow{d} &b \arrow{r} &c \arrow{d}\\
d\arrow{rr} & & e \arrow{r} & f \arrow{r} &g\\
h\arrow{rr} \arrow{u} & & i\arrow{u}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

You need to insert empty places in the second and in the third row and to double the arrows.